# Sublime video player in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, api

I am using sublime video player, but I got troubles accessing the javascript API in my controller in my AngularJS app. I am accessing it like this:

```
sublime.ready(function () { 
   var player = sublime('cacplayer'); 
});
```

But I am getting error with calling "ready" of undefined. But when I try accessing the sublime object right in the chrome console, it works perfectly. I have tried accessing the global object through $window, when the $viewContentLoaded event, but no luck on any front. What am I missing?

I thought that it was because the player is not loaded yet. So I included into the head of the page, no luck either. Using jQuery did not help either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's the error?  Maybe try sublime.load(); before calling sublime.ready()?